# Unable to install Magento Toolkit - No Repository Found

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install the [Magento Toolkit for Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/magento-toolkit-eclipse), but have been unsuccessful. I receive the following error

[image]

Session data:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_ZA
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product     org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
```

Is this just me or is the repository down?